# Запись в Internal storage

Tags: android, java

Друзья объясните мне вот какую штуку пожалуйста, весь день бьюсь не пойму что к чему.
Почему при объявлении переменной подсвечивается контекст:

```
File outputFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "filename");
```

ошибка:

```
 context cannot be resolved
```

ведь объявляю я её не как класс

P.S. импортированы следующие библиотеки:

```
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
```

Объясните бестолковому

Comment: Очевидно, что у вас не определена эта самая переменная `context`.

Comment: с большой буквы попробуй. или получи context от activity

Comment: хорошо, как эту переменную объявить? Сontext context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте существующий контекст — `Application`, `Activity`, `Service`. Например, если вышеприведённый код выполняется в наследнике `View`, то текущий контекст вы сможете получить вызовом `getContext()`, в случае `Fragment` — `getActivity()` и т.д. В остальных случаях контекст можно передать в качестве параметра метода/конструктора, или же передавать непосредственно готовый объект `File`.

Хотите конкретный совет — покажите больше кода. В частности, объявление класса, в котором он находится.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
   Context context;
   File myF = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "filename");

Comment: Поскольку `Activity` является наследником `Context`, то и наследует его методы, в частности `getFilesDir()`. Таким образом, эту строчку вы можете записать как:

    File myF = new File(getFilesDir(), "filename");